# How can you check if the person using the command is the owner?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I want the bot to reply with "You can't warn the owner!", but I can't seem to get the right code. Here is a snippet of my code:

```js
let id = '328248785933434881'
let ownerID = client.users.fetch(id);

if (message.mentions.has(ownerID))
  return message.channel.reply(`<@${message.author.id}>, you can\'t warn the owner...`);
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure `ownerID` should just be... `id`. Also `.reply()` automatically includes the person being replied to so no need to ping them a second time within the message.

Comment: Anyway, we need information on what's not working. What happens when you try your code?

Comment: When I try to do it, it just completely passes the if - return statement and warns me anyway.

Comment: `client.users.fetch` returns a Promise. You're not awaiting the Promise, therefore ownerID is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Found the solution. Works the same as what I was asking for, except it only works for single / personal servers instead of global bots.***

```js
const ownerID = 'OWNERS ID'
    if (message.mentions.has(ownerID)) return (message.channel.send(`You aren't allowed to warn <@${ownerID}>!`))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the owner of a server by searching the guild by the ID, like this:

```js
let guild = client.guilds.cache.get('GuildID');
console.log(guild.ownerID);
```

But if you want to skip extracting the ID from the mention and comparing it to `ownerID` then you can compare users like this:

```js
let guild = client.guilds.cache.get('GuildID');
if (message.mentions.has(guild.owner))
  return message.channel.send(`<@${message.author.id}>, you can\'t warn the owner...`);
```

Comment: Got this error: TypeError: client.guilds.get is not a function

Comment: Sorry, I have just udpated my answer

Comment: Could you make it with my code? Like copy my code and add it into mine, because I can't seem to place it right and keep gettng errors, like: TypeError: Cannot read property 'owner' of undefined

Comment: Are you sure you've got the right guild ID? My code should replace yours, not go before/after it.

Comment: Ah okay, well I removed ownerID and ID, but I still got the error owner undefined. I right clicked the name of my server and clicked copy ID.

Comment: I think `message.channel.reply` should be either `message.reply` or  `message.channel.send`. Anyway, there is my upvote :)

Comment: Thanks for spotting that! Totally missed it :)

Comment: There is only a single problem with your answer. It is that owner is invalid and undefined. I found a solution below, by the way. guild.owner wont work as "owner" was never defined.